# Check Free Space in Windows NT 5.1 and newer platforms in NSIS

Tags: path, nsis, diskspace

I am trying to use this script:

http://nsis.sourceforge.net/CheckSpaceFree

But it lacks some fundamental checks and adjustments ( comments ) for the case(s), where:

1) The $INSTDIR Path contains Program Files directory, which is Access protected, therefore, even if running setup with admin priviledges, you still get 0 integer return when, for example, your path ( absolute or relative ) lands on program files directory.

Failing Test path: `C:\Program Files(x86)\BlaBlaBla\`

Working test path: `C:\BlaBlaBla`

2) If I try to use relative path containing one level up (..\BlaBlaBla) AND point it to Disk root ( C:\ ), then path summerizes to `C:\..\BlaBlaBla` , resulting that nsis simply crashes.

Any best-pratice based way to gracefully work around these limitations?

Thank you all for any input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried [DriveSpace](https://github.com/NSIS-Handbook/Documentation/blob/master/Includes/FileFunc/DriveSpace.md) from the "useful headers" included with NSIS?

Comment: Woe. Umm, no ... Thank you very much. Looks promising. :) Maybe this should be also pointed in NSIS wiki of that CheckSpaceFree function... ? :) I guess it would help others run into same situation...

Comment: Actuqally I am a bit worried. The Wiki page is last modified in 3 February 2010, at 09:31 ... but the DriveSpace macro seems like is last on version v3.3, modified in year 2006. And the code, created on 2006 works better?

Comment: take a good look at the wiki diff. neither the 2007 nor the 2010 changes have been substantial, so i'd date this script to 2005. anyway, i'd simply *test* if the DriveSpace macro works for you.

Comment: Nop, idleberg, it does not work either... it simply needs to implement automatic up-one-level until there is excistamnt directory and check against it...